# Finding the row causing error in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, bigdata

I have a sql table with huge data. The snippet of it is shown below.

[image]

I want to change the 'ACCT_YR_MTH' column by subtracting a month and  represent it in 'yyyymm' format.

The query I have is given below.

```
select * from CLAIM_FACT where
ACCT_YR_MTH = to_char(add_months(to_date(to_char('$$Acct_Yr_Mth') || '01', 'yyyymmdd'), -1) , 
'yyyymm');
```

But I am getting an error saying 'Illegal year entered'. The snippet of the error is given below.

[image]

I am not sure why this error is occurring, and also how to check the row that is causing this error. .Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your subject line states "SQL Server" but you are clearly using Oracle...?

Comment: @Stu My bad. Changed the title. Thanks

Comment: You do not specify a pattern for the innermost to_char, so the result of that conversion may be anything. What is the data type of the acct_yr_mth column? If it is a date use trunc instead of to_char. If it is char or varchar you don't need to_char.

Comment: You may use [`validate_conversion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) after you fix other issues

Answer (score 1):

Your query mqakes no sense, but the `'$$Acct_Yr_Mth'` is  atring.
As the query lie i wrote below makes no sense, i thing you have there a Varoable that wasn't replaced

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CLAIM_FACT(Acct_Yr_Mth VARCHAR2(6))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO CLAIM_FACT VALUES ('198511')
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from CLAIM_FACT where
> Acct_Yr_Mth = to_char(add_months(to_date(Acct_Yr_Mth , 'yyyymm'), -1) , 
> 'yyyymm');
> ```

> ```
> | ACCT_YR_MTH |
> | :---------- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4183e4f04b365403115cf644c3610694)*